# Why var x = 5 work and not var n = a?

Tags: javascript, variables, console.log

Why am I able to write:

```
var x = 5;
console.log(x);
5
```

but when I write:

```
var n = a;
console.log(n);
Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined
```

Comment: Where is variable a declared?

Comment: Why do you get `Uncaught ReferenceError: a is not defined`? Well, you never defined `a`. Where did it come from?

Comment: Who upvoted this post? Who read it and thought to themselves "This question shows research effort"?

Comment: A question by a new user that gets 5 upvoted answers within 5 minutes can't be that bad.

Comment: @Coder That just means the answers are correct and the question is simple, not that the question itself is great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you don't have a variable `a`. Set it beforehand, like this:

```
var a = 10;
var n = a;  // n is now also 10
```

If you want a character string, enclose the characters in quotes:

```
var n = "a";  // n is now a character string, not a number
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are trying to print out put of  `n` which reference value of `a` which is undefined variable.

You are getting error instead of undefined because javascript does not allow you assignment of undeclared variable

Answer (score 2):

When you write

```
var n = a;
```

then it means to set n's value the same value as *variable a*. But you haven't defined `a` yet, so you get an error message.

I think you mean the *string* `"a"`, so use that:

```
var n = "a";
console.log(n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because `a` is not a defined variable as the error clearly states.

If you want to set `n` to the character `'a'`, then you need to put it in either single or double quotes.

```
n = 'a';
```

or

```
n = "a";
```

Answer (score 2):

to print a in console,

```
var n = "a";
console.log(n);
```

print some other variable

```
var a = 10;
var n = a;
console.log(n);
```